# Android 8. How do I know if the application is running?

Tags: java, android

I have two applications. In `APP1`, I need to find out if `APP2` is running. If not runned, then I need to start `LaunchIntent` of `APP2`, if runned I need to send `Broadcast` to `APP2`. With `API<=23` I used `AndroidProcesses` library with `getRunningAppProcesses()` and it worked fine. But with `API>23`  `getRunningAppProcesses()` returns its own process.

How do I know if `APP2` is running for `API>23`?

P.S. `UsageStats` is not suitable, it returns application usage statistics for a certain time, but this does not say anything, because the application can be started, but not used, and vice versa, just closed, and statistics on it still remained.

Comment: "I need to find out if APP2 is running" -- please define, in computer programming terms, what "running" means. Do you mean that it has an outstanding process? Do you mean that it has a visible activity? Do you mean that it has an activity in the foreground? Do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean that it has a running process!

Comment: Then why don't you send the broadcast in either case? Let APP2 decide whether to show a UI. Starting activity or sending a broadcast will create a process for APP2 if it does not already have one.

Comment: "sending a broadcast will create a process for APP2" - how? You want to say that Broadcast Receiver will work?!

Comment: "how?" -- `startActivity()`, `startService()`, `bindService()`, `sendBroadcast()` (when called on a `Context`), and `ContentResolver` operations start up a process for the other app as part of their normal work.

Comment: If I send broadcast to APP2, when APP2 is not running (no running process), who will recive the broadcast?

Comment: The behavior is identical, from APP1's standpoint, whether APP2 has a process or not. If APP1's broadcast identifies a component in APP2, Android will fork a process for APP2, if APP2 does not already have a running process.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you very much! It works!